# Is it possible to return data/models from controller to template via setRouteVariables?

Tags: plugin-development, templating, models, post

I'm trying to write a plugin that lives in the admin interface, that reads external data (a cinema program), parses it, and creates entries based on this (movie info and screening times).

While doing so I build a log of the additions/updates made, that I want to return to the template (the plugin page from where I trigger the update) and display the changes listed in a table. But I have trouble reading anything out with `craft.request.getPost()` from the template.

The log, basically an array of custom models (log items), seems to be fine while still in the controller. I try to pass this array via `craft()->urlManager->setRouteVariables()`, but at the template, it seems the only variables it finds are the `action` and `redirect` parameters from the original form.

The code in the controller looks like this:

```
$log = craft()->updateProgram_program->update();
craft()->urlManager->setRouteVariables(array(
   'log' => $log
));
```

And then I try to read the `log` variable in my template like this:

```
{% set log = craft.request.getPost('log') %}
```

Whatever I do, it seems to always be `NULL`. I've also tried to set a simple text string as the value, in case it's not possible to post an array like this, but it's still `NULL` when it comes to the template. It seems the `log` parameter is simply not found in the `POST` request at all.

Is there anything obvious I'm doing wrong?

I've scratched my head all day over this, so any tips are extremely welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are overwriting the `log` variable you are sending back to the template when you set log equal to the response of getPost.

From what I can see of your code, when you return variables to your template via `setRouteVariables`, you should be providing the variables you define in that array to your template, *without* having to take a second step and retrieve them.  So, when your controller returns:

```
craft()->urlManager->setRouteVariables(array(
   'log' => $log
));
```

You should then be able to access that variable in your template if it exists:

```
{% if log is defined %}
    {{ dump(log) }}
{% endif %}
```

---

`setRouteVariables` adds your variables to Twig's context, which you can see in your template by dumping `_context`:

```
{{ dump(_context) }}
```

Or, a handy way to just see the variables available in the context and not the full models is using the `keys` filter:

```
{{ dump(_context|keys) }}
```

---

In your case, I believe when your page reloads, your `log` variable is available, but then you set it to null when you try to retrieve it.

Your current code:

```
{# Sets log to null, because no post variable exists named `log` #}
{% set log = craft.request.getPost('log') %}

{% if log is defined %}
    {{ dump(log) }} {# outputs null #}
{% endif %}
```

Try outputting the log variable before setting your getPost value:

```
{# Outputs log if it exists in Twig's context #}
{% if log is defined %}
    {{ dump(log) }} {# will probably output your value #}
{% endif %}

{# Delete this. It just overwrites your existing log variable #}
{% set log = craft.request.getPost('log') %}
```

Comment: You are hero! This works like a charm. Thanks for not only saving this concrete situation, but now I also understand way better how things work, and what is accessible where, which I'm sure will save me a lot of headaches also down the road.